# Safari link unstyled after clicking it (opens in _blank). Re-styled after external window closed

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser

I have a website where all links are working normally in the major browsers except Safari. In Safari, if the user clicks on a link with target="_blank" and then goes back to the original tab, the link is no longer styled as a link. If you then close the newly opened tab, the link immediately updates to being styled.

That is:

In my site at https://mysite.umich.edu/myapp I have a link in this format:

```
<a href="http://www.umich.edu/~someplace/glossary.html#accept_role" target="_blank">Accept Role in our Glossary of Terms</a>
```

On the page, it looks like this:

[image: Link with styling]

When I click on that link, the linked-to URL (the glossary) opens up in a new tab, and I am taken to that tab. If I then go back to the tab where I started (https://mysite.umich.edu/myapp), the link is no longer styled as a link:

[image: Link without styling]

If then, staying on the original page, I close the newly opened tab (the one showing the glossary), the link will immediately go back to looking like the first screenshot above.

Debugging this is made more complicated by the fact that the problem doesn't happen if Developer Tools are open. Also, some sequence of clicks will make the problem go away, but I have not yet been able to reproduce that effect.

It seems like this must be some sort of timing issue in Safari. Does anyone have any clues about how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There does seem to be some sort of timing issue with Safari whereby it holds on to the CSS for A:HOVER in the original tab even after the user has moved the cursor away from the link, but this would not have been a problem if we had had a reasonable CSS rule for A:HOVER. Since our A:HOVER CSS rule set the text color to the same color as our default text, we could not, of course, distinguish the link from the surrounding text. Changing the CSS made this a non-issue.

So it seems like Safari is misbehaving, but in our situation, at least, there is a workaround.